How to make a bot kick a person when a channel got deleted?
So I'm trying to make my own custom bot to help moderate my Discord server. I managed to make the channel deletion detection system work, but I can't get the person kicked. This is the script:
  client.on('channelDelete', async (channel) => {
    // Get the channel ID
    const channelDeleteId = channel.id;
    
    // Fetch all channel deletions from the audit log
    const auditLogs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 12 });

    // Find the log entry for this specific channelrs

    const channelDeleteEntry = auditLogs.entries.find((entry) => entry.target.id === channelDeleteId);
    if (channelDeleteEntry) {
        const deleter = channelDeleteEntry.executor;
        const member = deleter
        member.kick();
        
        console.log(`User ${deleter.username} deleted channel ${channel.name} at time ${channelDeleteEntry.createdAt}`);

        
    }
});

I tried looking around forums but I didn't get answers
This was the error i got
node:events:495
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: member.kick is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Real-Anti-Raid-Bot\src\index.js:167:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:398:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)

Node.js v18.20.3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

When i console.log what the member/deleter is it says this :
User {
  id: '1081421289081819187',
  bot: false,
  system: false,
  flags: UserFlagsBitField { bitfield: 256 },
  username: 'linate_official',
  globalName: 'linate official',
  discriminator: '0',
  avatar: 'c69e831815aaadb18c61cfaa38151e21',
  banner: null,
  accentColor: null,
  avatarDecoration: null
}

It says all about my profile.

This question is similar to: Discord.js TypeError: member.kick is not a function. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are calling the kick function on a User object, instead of on a GuildMember object. To get the GuildMember object you can do this:
if (channelDeleteEntry) {
    const deleter = channelDeleteEntry.executor;
    const member = await channel.guild.members.fetch(deleter.id);
    member.kick();
}

An easier way might be to just call the kick function directly on the GuildMemberManager returned with channel.guild.members:
if (channelDeleteEntry) {
     const deleter = channelDeleteEntry.executor;
     channel.guild.members.kick(deleter);


The first codeblock would not work because .fetch() returns a promise which you would need to resolve (await)

Thanks for pointing this out MrMythical, fixed!
